# sampling a fixed number of unique pairs from a population

Tags: python-3.x, sampling

I have a sample of `n` elements.  I want to sub-sample `m` unique pairs from `n`.
Is there a simple off-the-self method to do this in python ?

For example, if `n = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and `m = 3`, one such sample will be [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]

Comment: I assume you want the samples to be random?

Comment: @retnikt yes.  it has to be random.

Answer (score 1):

The `random` module has a [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) function which will pick `n` unique items from a collection. You can then pair them up to create your desired output:

```py
import random
import itertools

data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
m = 3

def pairwise(iterable):
    # from the itertools cookbook: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

chosen = random.sample(data, m * 2)
result = pairwise(chosen)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean precisely with 'random', the answer will differ!

For uniform sampling of unique pairs, assuming all elements of your list are distinct:

```
import itertools, random
n, m = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 3
x = random.sample( list(itertools.permutations(n,2)), m)
print(x) #e.g. [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```